# Define front end controller for specific application in project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I created a front end controller within a project containing multiple (REST) applications. The issue is now that, the controller gets applied for all applications I try to access through the browser. I would like to ask whether the is a configuration or annotation to define for which application the controller should get applied.

This is the code of the controller:

```
@Controller
public class FrontendController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

In the same package the application which serves the front end sources is implemented:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tell server to look for web-server.properties or web-server.yml
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "web-server");

        SpringApplication.run(com.studienarbeit.chaoscenter.services.departments.DepartmentsServer.class, args);
    }

}
```

The other applications are in different packages and yet they still serve the front end sources. There are no other controllers in the project and the other applications use Spring Data REST repositories.

**Note:** Each application runs on its own port.

**Note 2:** I tried the approach using a profile for the controller:

```
@Profile("web-server")
```

Since I work with IntelliJ, I set the active profile to `web-server` and add the following flag in the VM Options for the specific application:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=web-server
```

Somehow still my other applications access the front end controller. Maybe I did miss something?

**Note 3:** The other application implementations look basically exactly like the `WebServer` application and they use Spring Data REST repositories which look like this:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

Comment: you may achieve this using spring profiles if you want to go with it

Comment: @PatelRomil I did try that, but somehow it didn't work out. I updated the answer regarding this approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use specific RequestMapping values for each of your controller classes like :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/controller1")
public class FrontendController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

So you would consume this endpoint with the url `http://localhost:8080/controller1`

Also, if you're not going to use Mvc Views and this will be only a Rest Controller, use @RestController insted @Controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/controller1")
public class FrontendController
```

It's a combination of `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` annotations. Detailed information could be found at [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Each of my applications is running on different ports, since they are implemented as micro services. Also it would be great to keep the index path as "/" - is there no other option to solve this? Or somehow to specify the port for the controller?

Comment: So, your other controllers have request mappings as "/" and they have @Controller annotations, and they are running on different ports. Let's say another one runs in 8081, and you access it with http://localhost:8081 right?

Well it should return you what you define in Get method for "/" path. I'm not sure i understand your problem here. If you do not want it to serve Mvc Views, you should change your Controller to RestController, this way it'll only return Json/Xml response. But as long as you have request mapping to "/", it'll return you some response.

Comment: There is currently only one controller which is applied for all my application despite them being in other packages. The other applications have no controllers but use Spring Data REST repositories to handle incoming requests.

Comment: I'm sorry if i misunderstood your problem. Can you show an example of these repositories ? Are they annotated @RepositoryRestResource ? And what do you mean by "my other applications access the front end controller", how are they access it ?

Comment: Just updated my question. Maybe I did misjudged my problem and the issue is not the controller at all. I assumed that the controller is responsible for serving the front end (template files). But maybe all my Spring Boot applications serve the template files per default and all I have to do is to disable the front end for the other applications.

Comment: I am currently not at my notebook, but I will later try to remove the FronendController and check how it will behave.

Comment: Yeah the problem is not connected with the front end controller. I guess each application looks by default in my template directory for an index.html. Now I will try to find out how to disable the template access for the other applications. Thank you